# My array of texture2D references is never assigned to, what can I do?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am making this game for a school project where you have different types of invaders showing on the screen.

My idea was to make an array with texture2D references "textures" and then pick a random one and assign that reference to a new variable named "texture".

Now when I start up my program it throws a nullreferenceException. Also, it highlights both my texture and texture variables and says they are never assigned to? Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace MonoGameInvaders
{
    class Invader
    {
        public Vector2 position;
        public Vector2 velocity;
        public Texture2D [] textures;
        public Texture2D texture;

        public Invader()
        {
            textures[0] = Global.content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_red_invader");
            textures[1] = Global.content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_blue_invader");
            textures[2] = Global.content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_green_invader");
            textures[3] = Global.content.Load<Texture2D>("yellow_invader");
            Init();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            position = new Vector2(Global.Random(100, Global.width - 100), Global.Random(0, Global.height - 300));
            velocity = new Vector2(3.0f, 10.0f);
            switch (Global.Random(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: texture = textures[0];break;
                case 1: texture = textures[1];break;
                case 2: texture = textures[2];break;
                case 3: texture = textures[3];break;
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            position.X += velocity.X;

            if ((position.X > Global.width - texture.Width) || (position.X < 0))
            {
                position.X -= velocity.X;
                velocity.X = -velocity.X;
                position.Y += velocity.Y;
            }
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            Global.spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not initialized either initialize it with the correct size or use a list instead:

```
private var textures = new List<Texture2D>();
```

and add your assets

```
textures.Add(Global.content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_red_invader"));
```

You can still access them by index.